# how to change the name of project in vc++ 2008( in vs2008)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I have created a vc++ MDI application. Now i want to rename it so that the name on the application main window is the new name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit of a filthy hacky process this, but I've had to do it many a time...

Close the solution, leaving VS2008 open.

First you might want to make a backup of the current solution folder, unless you're using version control.

Now use Edit -> Find&Replace -> Find In Files to search for your current application name, in the solution folder recursively.

Open each occurrence, change it to the new name and save the file.

Close VS2008.

In the solution folder rename the *.vsproj and project folder to the new name.

Reopen VS2008 and the solution, and check it all works fine.

Comment: Is that the best of solutions

Comment: Is there a way tochange the name of main application window other than this?

Comment: Jeez!! That was a hell of a way out but it worked!! just left out header files and resource files with out renaming. does renaming them cause errors?

Comment: Oops I forgot about those. Yeah I'd rename everything, there's absolutely no reason not to :)

Answer (score 1):

Do a grep for IDR_MAINFRAME in your resource files (.rc and .rc2). If you find a string table entry, modify it with your application name. If you don't find one, add a string table entry.

Comment: Modifying string table results in errors. as i have renamed all .h and .cpp and .rc files. And how to do a GREP